# Informix: What's the best mode to perform "disk" operations and why?

Tags: database, informix

I'm doing some administrative work with Informix IDS. I have to create some dbspaces, sbspaces, etc.

Which mode is better to make this changes? Quiescent, or Single-user? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.

In IDS 11, appears not to be a "best way", but ther's a new mode out there, named "Administrative mode". It's like single-user mode, but for more than one user. In other words something like ‘Mostly-Single-User mode’

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that for many purposes, the best mode is 'OnLine' (normal operating) mode.  This allows you to add the dbspaces etc while users are still using the system.  The disadvantage of that is that someone who you didn't want to use the new space might get a chance to do so, but then you need to think about who has what sorts of administrative access to your system.  After adding the spaces, you'll need to make some backups.  That too can be done while the server is 'OnLine'.

However, there are legitimate reasons for considering Administrative (single-user) mode, or Quiescent mode.  If you're trying to drop things, in particular, it can be a confounded nuisance if users connect and try to access the object you're trying to drop.  Then the Administrative mode is a godsend.  You chuck all the mortals off the system and get on without them interfering with you.

Comment: Wow. I've asked this a long time ago. Great answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Only really noticed it today — apologies for not getting you a decent answer sooner, though your own answer is not bad.